# Get ID of filtered element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have multiple elements that share a class. At any given time, one of them may be visible. I can determine that one of them is visible, but how do I get it's ID?

n is the ID of an element that has been clicked, 1-4. I want to see if n matches the ID of the visible element so that no action is taken if the matching element is already visible. If you have already clicked one of them and made something visible, clicking again should do nothing. So, which element in c is the visible element - need it's ID.

```
function manageVisible(n) {
       var x = n, i, c;
       c = $('.glowSafe:visible');
       if(c.length !=0){
           c.fadeOut(300).hide();
           $('#glowSafe' + x).fadeIn(800);
       }
       $('#glowSafe' + x).fadeIn(800);
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var theId = $('.glowSafe:visible').prop('id'); // jQuery >= 1.6
var theId = $('.glowSafe:visible').attr('id'); // jQuery <  1.6
```

Now you can use the above:

```
if (n !== theId)
    ...
```

Comment: Although the use of prop is encouraged, your statement is not entirely right. "id" is always an attribute, thus, should be accessed as such. `attr()` is not deprecated, it should be used accordingly. http://api.jquery.com/prop/ does a good job showing the difference

Comment: @Adrian. I remember I once saw jQuery docs using prop for `id`, anyway this is completely valid, (and extremely not critical...)

Comment: i was missing the quotes around id when i was doing it yesterday...doh! thank you.

Answer (score 0):

To get the ID of the visible element of that class:

```
var id = $('.glowSafe:visible').attr("id");
```

or, since you already have that the element in `c` variable:

```
c = $('.glowSafe:visible');
var id = c.attr("id");
```